# WavPack for html audio playback

Tags: html, http, audio, mime-types, wav

I wanted to write a little website which provides quite long audio playbacks.
Because I have a very limited webspace I wanted to compress the .wav files I have with the tool [wavpack](http://www.wavpack.com/). The compression works pretty good and the vlc media player is able to play the file but used within a website via the audio tag it does not work. I noticed that windows is not able to display the bitrate nor the length of the audio file in its detail page maybe this is an  indicator that the file is not properly converted/compressed?

Does someone know if the current browser support wavpack, what the correct MIME type would be or if there is another lossless compression for .wav files.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no MIME type for *WavPack* (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) and [there](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php?PHPSESSID=goh5r02r2dn9v3dambihef6rr4&topic=84701.msg729653#msg729653)).

But that's probably not a problem! Actually, in the default mode, *WavPack* only compacts your WAV files. As mentioned on their website (emphasis mine):

> In the default lossless mode **WavPack acts just like a WinZip compressor** for audio files. However, unlike MP3 or WMA encoding which can affect the sound quality, **not a single bit of the original information is lost**…

So, if you use the default mode:

- you gain ***a bit*** of disk space/bandwidth compared to the original audio
- you don't lose any quality

For the purpose of a website, you would be better off encoding your files to a lossy format (AAC, Ogg Vorbis, MP3, etc.) which will give you a real compression gain.

In the end, you have two solutions:

1. **You don't care about bandwidth / You care about quality:** Use pure WAV files
2. **You care about bandwidth / You care less about quality:** Use AAC or Ogg Vorbis